# how i deploy image from container registry to azure kubernete service AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am not able to deploy registry image to Azure Kubernetes

i have one image name hello-world in azure container registry .Now i want this image will be manages by Kubernetes service .

i follow this link  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application)

but not able to understand manifest file and how i generate "yml" file

i pull image from docker registry and push to private container registry .Now my images are kept in azure container registry .Now i want to deploy to AKS  from conatiner registry .But how i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration)

1. Establish an authentication mechanism between AKS and ACR
2. Ensure you have the proper AKS credentials using `az aks get-credentials -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster`
3. Apply the kubernetes deployment yaml to AKS